# How to make sure that incoming object is a base type (String, Int16, Int32, Double...)?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

So I have the method:

```
public Boolean IsItABaseType(object obj)
{
    // How to make sure that this incoming obj
    // is a base type (String, Int32, Double, Int16, Decimal...).
    Boolean isBaseType = obj...
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(obj).Name);
    Console.WriteLIne("obj is base type"+isBaseType);
}
```

How to make sure that this incoming obj is a base type (String, Int32, Double, Int16, Decimal...)?

**EDIT**

As a "base type" I mean all primitive types known to the C#.

Comment: Can you be clear what meaning of "Base" type you are using? Because all of those are either `struct` or `sealed class`; the one thing we can say for sure is that they are ***not*** a "base type" for *anything*

Comment: @Joey however, `string` does not describe itself as a primitive; `typeof(string).IsPrimitive` is `false`. Hence the need to be very precise about what exactly the OP *wants*.

Comment: Yup, you need to give us your rule for what a "base type" is. Another guess might be that "It's a type in the `System` namespace and implemented in `mscorlib`"

Comment: @Joey that is my point: the *purpose* of that question is to make the OP stop and think: "what exactly *do* I mean here?"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so `System.Console`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems everyone is doing it really complicated, with long lists of conditions or big `switch` statements.

There are multiple possible interpretations of what you think of as primitive types.

#### 1. .NET primitive types

.NET has a list of types that it considers to be primitive types. On the [`Type` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx) there is a property [`IsPrimitive` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) that will return `true` for any of these primitive types and `false` for any other type.

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

Note that `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` are also in there. They represent the platform-specific integer type (e.g. 32-bit integer on a 32-bit computer, 64-bit on a 64-bit computer). Also note that .NET does not consider `String` or `Decimal` to be a primitive.

You can test it like this:

```
public static bool IsPrimitiveType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsPrimitive;
}
```

#### 2. .NET primitive types and String and Decimal

In your question you have included the `String` and `Decimal` types in your definition of a primitive type. Let's test for those too, like this:

```
public static bool IsPrimitiveType(Type type)
{
    return type.IsPrimitive
        || type == typeof(decimal)
        || type == typeof(string);
}
```

Since it is impossible to extend `String` or `Decimal`, simple type equality will suffice here.

#### 3. Built-in C# types

If your definition of primitive types is the list of [Built-in Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) on MSDN, we have to exclude `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` because they are not in that list.

```
public static bool IsPrimitiveType(Type type)
{
    return (type.IsPrimitive
         && type != typeof(UIntPtr)
         && type != typeof(IntPtr))
        || type == typeof(decimal)
        || type == typeof(string);
}
```

#### 4. Something else entirely

Based on the previous examples you can see how to exclude or include additional types in your definition of a *primitive type* if you want to.

---

In all the above examples, you can call the `IsPrimitiveType` method like this:

1. If you have an object instance `obj`:

   ```
   bool isPrimitive = IsPrimitiveType(obj.GetType());
   ```
2. If you have a type `someType`:

   ```
   bool isPrimitive = IsPrimitiveType(someType);
   ```
3. If you have a generic type parameter `T`:

   ```
   bool isPrimitive = IsPrimitiveType(typeof(T));
   ```
4. If you have a type known at compile time, e.g. `Int32`:

   ```
   bool isPrimitive = IsPrimitiveType(typeof(Int32));
   ```

Answer (score 7):

There is no automatic list of "built in" types in the runtime, since different languages can have different built-in support for types.

> As a "base type" i mean all primitive types known to the C#.

So we can use the [Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ya5y69ds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deduce:

```
switch(Type.GetTypeCode(obj.GetType()) {
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
    case TypeCode.Byte:
    case TypeCode.SByte:
    case TypeCode.Char:
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
    case TypeCode.Double:
    case TypeCode.Single:
    case TypeCode.Int32:
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
    case TypeCode.Int64:
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
    case TypeCode.Int16:
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
    case TypeCode.String:
      // do stuff for "built in" types
      ...
      break;
   default:
      // do stuff for all other types
      ...
      break;
}
```

Note I omitted `object`, for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: I dislike idea to make it all throgh the switch case. Is there any method or property in the reflection that can let me be sure that the type is primitive and known in the c#. I always known about this way. But I try to automize this way and I hope that there is any way to do it.

Comment: @Maris as I included in my answer, the second of those is problematic: "known in the c#" is not something that the ***runtime*** (reflection etc) cares about, since it needs to support multiple languages. "is primitive" depends on "what definition of primitive are you using?" - for example, `string` both "is" and "isn't" a primitive, depending on how you define "primitive". In .NET / runtime terms, it is *not* a primitive.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isBaseType = obj is string || obj is int || obj is double || obj is decimal ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can.....
`if (obj == typeof(double)) blablblabl;
if (obj == typeof(int)) blablablaaa2;`

Hope can help you think through it

Answer (score 0):

Use instanceof operator

```
assert (obj instanceof Integer || obj instanceof Boolean|| obj instanceof String|| obj instanceof Double|| obj instanceof Short|| obj instanceof Long|| obj instanceof Float|| obj instanceof Chracter) : "input is not a valid datatype";
```

the above code will throw an assertion error is the type is not a primitive type or null.

Answer (score 0):

So I get how to do it!

```
    var t = obj.GetType();
    Boolean isInSystemNameSpace = t.Namespace == "System";
    var result = t == typeof(string) || t.IsValueType && isInSystemNameSpace;
```

This will do what I wanted. Thx a lot to the people who tried to help me!

Comment: There are 115 value-types in the "System" namespace that will return `true` to this, just in mscorlib alone. If we add `&& !t.IsNested && !t.IsEnum` to your test, it comes down to 44. If we add `&& t.IsPublic` we get down to 30. Things like `System.RuntimeFieldHandle`, `System.TypedReference`, etc

Comment: Yeap, you are right. Add `&& !t.IsNested && !t.IsEnum && t.IsPublic` is a good idea. If you will renew your answer I will accept it as a answer. Thank you very much for your activity in my question.